# Does a power that does damage on Hit and with an Effect gain from vulnerability twice?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage

I'm looking specifically at [Bloodbath](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10757).

[image: Bloodbath]

As you can see the power deals 1 [W] + Dexterity modifier damage on both the **Hit** and the **Effect**.

Do both the hit and the effect gain from vulnerability? Or do I calculate my total damage and then apply the vulnerability?

Let's say it was a [Frost Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=187). Does the bonus from [Gloves of Ice](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=5805) apply once or twice?

Comment: Part of the question is, does the vulnerability even come in to play for the Effect portion. Let's see what people have to say http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/does-the-weapon-damage-type-apply-to-effect-damage

Comment: *huh* funky question. Nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vulnerability triggers each time a creature takes damage:

> If you have vulnerable 5 fire, then any time you take fire damage, you take an additional 5 fire damage.

In this case, the target takes damage twice: Once when the power hits, and a second time when the effect triggers. As vulnerability is tied to taking damage rather than being hit, each instance of damage will receive the bonus.

Comment: I guess it's dependent on the language for each source of increased damage then. Gloves of Ice say "+2 to damage rolls" so I suppose it applies twice as well, since I'm rolling damage twice.

Comment: Interesting... Frozen Whetstone states "any successful attack with the weapon deals an extra 2 cold damage". So that would only apply once for Bloodbath. I think they need to standardize the wording of these things!

Comment: I think the Frozen Whetstone would do damage twice as well, since the effect is a successful attack from the weapon. (i.e. 1[W] )

Comment: @dpatchery, you're correct: there are things that trigger on successful attack (anything on the hit line) and things that trigger on damage rolled (anything within a damage expression that uses dice). It's very language dependent.

Comment: Just to put in, I would also add that same source only works once, but once on the type of effect.  Since the Hit is happening once and you did hit, then you damaged them, all sources can be applied once.  Since the effect while part of the same source in terms of power, its happening on a different section, the sources would all trigger once again.  The only time this would be an exception would basically be if it said "once per round" or "once per turn"

Answer (score 0):

Effects happen regardless of hit or not, they just happen, but they only happen once.  They happen after the Hit is resolved, so I'm thinking that yes, it applies twice, but only twice.