# Does the weapon damage type apply to Effect damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

This is more general variation of a part of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8631/does-a-power-that-does-damage-on-hit-and-with-an-effect-gain-from-vulnerability-t).

If an attack power has an Effect that does damage (ex: [Bloodbath](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10757)), and the target is vulnerable to the damage type which the weapons causes (ex: [Frost Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=187)), does the vulnerability get added to the Effect damage?

For simplicity sake, let's assume the attack missed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

A `weapon` power that has an `effect` that deals damage clearly falls under the wording of Frost Weapon:

> **All** damage dealt by this weapon is cold damage.

And on vulnerability,

> A creature that is vulnerable to a specified damage type usually takes a specific amount of extra damage when it takes damage of that type, or it suffers a specific **effect**. For example, a creature that has vulnerable 10 radiant takes 10 extra radiant damage when an attack deals radiant damage to it or when it takes ongoing radiant damage.

Vulnerability doesn't say anything about a power having to *hit* the target, just that it needs to take damage of that type. It's also pretty clear that vulnerability affects effects because the rules specifically mention ongoing damage, which is exclusively an effect.

Comment: The crux of the question is, is the Effect considered to be damage done by the weapon? The fact that it uses [W] for damage in Bloodbath implies "yes", but that's not always the case.

Comment: Hmm.. I see your point, but I can't think of a reason that damage done by a `weapon` power wouldn't be considered damage done by the weapon, even if it is an effect.

Comment: I might be able to help on this since in a way, it has the semi-similarity to Plague of Frogs.  The short answer would be: Yes.  It will apply only because that as an effect, it doesn't have to hit.  It happens regardless and as DP initially quoted, it happens and would apply.  Basically, add Cold keyword to the power and it would be the exact same thing so you'd still apply it and to be clearer, if it had a miss damage (e.g. half damage) it would still be cold damage.  So DP had it on the nose.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The power has the weapons keyword on it and then it makes perfect sense. If you could rephrase the answer to emphasize that, I would be more than happy to mark it as the accepted answer.